# How to have a function with a nullable string parameter in Go?

Tags: string, parameters, go

I'm used to Java's String where we can pass null rather than "" for special meanings, such as **use a default value**.

In Go, string is a primitive type, so I cannot pass nil (null) to a parameter that requires a string.

I could write the function using pointer type, like this:

```
func f(s *string)
```

so caller can call that function either as

```
f(nil)
```

or

```
// not so elegant
temp := "hello";
f(&temp)
```

but the following is unfortunately not allowed:

```
// elegant but disallowed
f(&"hello");
```

What is the best way to have a parameter that receives either a string or nil?

Comment: I believe you need to let go of Java, and get used to Go way instead. Why do you need to pass a nil instead of a string? what do you want to achieve? ps. you can also use fmt.Printf(*new(string)) - which is 'zero' for the type string

Comment: @ŁukaszGruner How is it a Java thing? “Why do you need to pass a `nil` instead of a `string`?” Because I need to _not_ pass any `string`, including `""`!

Answer (score 5):

**Warning**: the following is pre-Go1 code. That is, it's from a pre-release version and is not valid Go code.

I thought some more about how I would implement this using a `struct`. Here's what I came up with:

```
type MyString struct {
    val string;
}

func f(s MyString) {
    if s == nil {
        s = MyString{"some default"};
    }
    //do something with s.val
}
```

Then you can call `f` like this:

```
f(nil);
f(MyString{"not a default"});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to handle a possibble null value (becasue you are talking to a database that may provide them for example) the `database/sql` package has types such as `sql.NullString` and `sql.NullInt64` that allow you to test if you have been provided with a value or not using their `.Valid` field.

Answer (score 1):

Not realy attend answer : but warping value in a structure can provide some generic utility methode. ([Haskell Maybe](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/maybe.html) ?)

```
//#maybe.go
package maybe

import "log"

type MayHaveValue struct {
 IsValue bool;
}

func (this MayHaveValue) IsJust() bool {
 return this.IsValue
}

type AString struct {
 MayHaveValue;
 Value string;
}

func String(aString string) AString {
 return AString{MayHaveValue{true}, aString}
}

var NoString AString = AString{MayHaveValue{false}, ""}

func (this AString) String() (value string) {
 if this.IsJust() == true {
  value = this.Value;
 } else {
  log.Crash("Access to non existent maybeString value");
 }
 return;
}

func (this AString) OrDefault(defaultString string) (value string) {
 if this.IsJust() {
  value = this.Value;
 } else {
  value = defaultString;
 }
 return;
}

//#main.go
package main

import "fmt"
import "maybe"

func say(canBeString maybe.AString) {
 if canBeString.IsJust() {
  fmt.Printf("Say : %v\n", canBeString.String());
 } else {
  fmt.Print("Nothing to say !\n");
 }
}

func sayMaybeNothing (canBeString maybe.AString) {
 fmt.Printf("Say : %v\n", canBeString.OrDefault("nothing"));
}

func main() {
 aString := maybe.String("hello");
 say(aString);
 sayMaybeNothing(aString);
 noString := maybe.NoString;
 say(noString);
 sayMaybeNothing(noString);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare an interface to restrict the type to `string`, and since interfaces also accept `nil`, you'd have both cases covered. This is how you can implement it:

```
type (
    // An interface which accepts a string or a nil value.
    //
    // You can pass StrVal("text") or nil.
    StrOrNil interface{ isStrOrNil() }

    StrVal string // A string value for StrOrNil interface.
)

func (StrVal) isStrOrNil() {} // implement the interface
```

And this is how you use it:

```
func Foo(name StrOrNil) {
    switch nameVal := name.(type) {
    case StrVal:
        fmt.Printf("String value! %s\n", string(nameVal))
    default:
        fmt.Println("Null value!")
    }
}

func main() {
    Foo(StrVal("hello world"))
    Foo(nil)
}
```

Test it in the [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/E-ko5en83l2).

Comment: What is the performance impact of this? Would you provide further information on e.g. heap allocations?

Comment: @SOFe There is no heap allocation involved, other than the creation of the string itself. `StrVal` is a type alias (zero cost), and `StrOrNil` is an interface to restrict the type.

Comment: Wrapping a non-pointer value in an interface usually results in a heap allocation. A string is a struct that contains an int that is the length of the string and a pointer to the array that contains the characters of the string. Interfaces can only hold pointers so when you put a string in an interface it allocates the string struct on the heap and puts a pointer to this string in the interface. That means that you may end up with two pointers, something like `interface{&stringStruct{&charArray{}}}`

Answer (score -3):

Loose the Java-think and just pass f(""). Then test using len():

func f(str string) {
    if len(str) > 0 {
       ...
    } else {
       ...
    }
}

Either the string is empty and has semantic meaning of you nil case, or else has some string data to process. Can't see the problem with that.

Comment: The problem is that you may have null strings as ordinary parameters, not meaning "the default". What you suggest is "in-band signaling" (like using 0 or -1 for an integer) and is widely seen as a bad idea because you may need the "special" value for an ordinary meaning.